# Copy User id file from Lotus Domino Id Vault using java

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have a requirement to extract newly created user id file from ID Vault and send it the user programmatically using java and DIIOP. I have explored web and found there is Registration.getIdFromServer() method in NCSO.jar but it is not working.
There is a class IdVault for same purpose but don't know how to access it as there is no implementation in notes.jar or ncso.jar.

Comment: What version of Notes/Domino are you working with?

Comment: The `IDVault` class is relatively new to the back-end classes.  I think it was added after 9.0.1 Gold (in a Feature Pack).  Like many newer classes, it is implemented in notes.jar, but it is not implemented in ncso.jar.  In other words, it is not available through DIIOP.  I don't know about `Registration.getIdFromServer()`.  Perhaps someone else has some experience with that.

Comment: I am using Domino Release 9.0.1 (Oct 2013). Is there any other way to access/extract user id file programmatically?

Comment: The other way of doing it would be with a server-based agent that uses notes.jar instead of NCSO.jar.  That could be an HTTP agent, and your remote Java code could invoke the?OpenAgent URL via the URLConnection class. The most direct way would be for the HTTP agent to return the file as base64-encoded content in the response. An indirect way would be for the agent to create a new document and attach the id file, protect it with a readernames field so that nobody else can read it, and respond with the document's UNID so that you can read and then delete it via the regular API in NCSO.jar.

Comment: Thanks Richard...I will try it